# Print pointer in OpenCL

Tags: c++, pointers, printf, opencl

Can I print a pointer in an OpenCL function?
I can use printf in kernel functions however I can't find the way to print a pointer.

Is there some equivalent to the following?:

```
int *ptr = 5;
printf("%p \n", (void *)ptr);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you'd want to print a pointer? I imagine the address would be meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong with this?

```
int x = 5;
int *ptr;
ptr = &x;
printf("%p \n", ptr);
```

You can't make `ptr` point to 5. Pointers must point to memory on:

The stack: `int x` 
 or
 the heap: `int* ptr = new int(5)`

Comment: question is for printing pointer inside OpenCL kernel, printf just got its support in OpenCL 1.2 spec AFAIK most of the implementation Intel,AMD,NVIDIA doesn't support printing address from inside the kernel see here for printf fn : http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/printfFunction.html